# How to get File from file i upload to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I upload an image to Firebase Storage for `profil_image`,
with this code

```
                StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("Profil_photo/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                reference.putBytes(dataarray).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"gambar berhasil di upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Proses Upload "+(int)progress + "%");
                    }
                });
            }
```

I am still a newbie, how to retrieve images that I can use in my home menu

I has try to use `Uri downloadURL = tasksnapshot.getDownloadURL` but i can't found `getDownloadurl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()
```

and then store the download URL to the database.

How to read

- query database for store downloaded URL and use in view.